# Android: copy/paste bar gets pushed out of screen by soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-actionbar, copy-paste

When i double touch on a word in my edittext the copy/paste bar shows. Thats fine.
The Problem is that the copy/paste bar appears out of the screen. Seems to.. it get´s pushed up by the soft keyboard. See the Screenshot.

[image]

My question: How can make the copy/paste bar fixed, so it won´t move?

I use "adjustPan" in the Manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution to my problem.
Maybe it is helpful to someone else ...

1. use **adjustResize** instead of **adjustPan** in the Manifest
2. Surround your xml layout with a **ScrollView**
3. Also specify a **android:minHeight** for your EditText

This did not work, when i used a RelativeLayout as main view for my ScrollView. So you better use a LinearLayout or FrameLayout etc...

=)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem . I used **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"**
in Manifest. Hope this works. Because **adjustResize** and **adjustPan** didn't solve my issue.